# Problem with two equations (matrix approximation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I've been reading a book and I don't know if both these equations refer to the same thing.

First equation (low rank matrix approximation):$$
\widehat{\boldsymbol{A}}(k):=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_{i} \boldsymbol{u}_{i} \boldsymbol{v}_{i}^{\top}
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{u}_{i},\boldsymbol{v}_{i}$ are two vectors, and $\sigma_{i}$ a scalar.

Second equation (beginning of an Eckart-Young Theorem explanation):$$
\widehat{\boldsymbol{A}}(k)=\operatorname{argmin}_{\mathrm{rk}(\boldsymbol{B})=k}\|\boldsymbol{A}-\boldsymbol{B}\|_{2}
$$

Where A and B are both matrices of the same size.

I can't seem to find the similarity between both $\widehat{\boldsymbol{A}}(k)$s; in the first one $\widehat{\boldsymbol{A}}(k)$ is (seems to be atleast) a matrice and in the seconde one it's a real number.

Can someone please correct my understanding?

Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: No, in the second one, it is also a matrix : the matrix $B$ which realizes the minimum among those with rank=$k$. In both cases, it is connected to the SVD decomposition.

Comment: Doesn't the second equation returns a real number k at which $\|\boldsymbol{A}-\boldsymbol{B}\|_{2}$ is at its lowest. Can you please give more detail to your answer? I didn't quite understand your response. Thanks

Comment: It is the very meaning of **arg** $\color{red}{max}$ for y = f(x) which returns the **argument** $x$ $\color{red}{maximizing}$ the $y$ ...

Comment: Are you saying that return value is actually the matrix B not the real number k?

Comment: That's it... I remember myself asking the same type of question on the first time I met argmin.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you very much